# Mongoengine Django Custome User Authentication

Tags: django, mongodb, authentication, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I am trying to handle my authentication and user system, with django restframework, using mongodb as my database. I've searched the whole internet for a good sample of code for my purpose to work.
But you may know that any article which is published in this issue doesn't work and you have so many errors while running the code.

does anyone know a good piece of code or an article that may help?

Comment: may be you should try https://medium.com/@9cv9official/django-to-mongodb-djongo-or-mongoengine-d9d56b836a3d